# React importing file automatically and causing build error?

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, sass

I am trying to use "npm start" to build and locally host a front-end that I have been given, but I am running into an issue.

In the style.scss file there is no mention of importing _variables.scss and it is in fact a blank file. I am new to react and would love any explanation on what is happening here.

```
Module build failed:

^
      File to import not found or unreadable: (DELETED_personal_PATH)/../src/styles/config/_variables.scss.
     (DELETED_personal_PATH)\src\components\SomeComp\style.scss (line 1, column 1)
```

Comment: Are there any references to `variables` in the project?

Comment: It definitely exists as I can open that file and view that its empty. One wierd thing is that the path that shows up for _variables.scss is very convoluted and looks incorrect.

Comment: Unless there is an import for it (`@import "variables";`) webpack should not be trying to find it

Comment: That's what I figured and when I check the style.scss file in that component it is completely blank. Thus, the line 1,colum1

Comment: are you pulling in any other styles or libraries in your project that might be pulling in this file?

Comment: No, not that I can find.